# Are my old websites being properly redirected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, heroku

About a year ago I merged three websites (oldsite.com, oldsite.nu, newsite.se) into one, which I kept on one of the domains (newsite.se). I am not sure if this has been done right since I still see a lot of traffic from Google for old url:s, even after a year.

**Oldsite redirect code**

---

*Important edit note*: I recently realized the nameservers were not pointing towards my old rails app any longer but instead to a php-folder on my web host in which I have a .htaccess with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.se/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

> **This makes this section below (regarding oldsite.com/oldsite.nu) void:**
>   The .com and .nu were built in Ruby on Rails and hosted on Heroku.
>
> The logic to redirect *paths* from oldsite.com/oldsite.nu were made
>   completely on the newsite.se site. The redirection code on the
>   oldsites is a straightforward redirection with this on the first row
>   in routes.rb on oldsite.com:
>
> ```
>   match "/(*path)" => redirect {|params, req| "http://www.newsite.se/#{params[:path]}"},  via: [:get, :post]
> ```

I used this (Swedish) tool to verify that this redirect actually makes a 301 redirect: http://301redirect.se . It confirmed the redirections were 301.

**Newsite.se redirection handler**

The content on each old website were matched with the same content on the new one, quite rarely on the same path, e.g.

```
oldsite.com/categories/vacation/item/1243
```

could lead to

```
newsite.se/product-items/1243
```

I handle these types of redirections mostly in an internal redirection controller that catches and redirects any traffic on newsite.se like:

```
newsite.se/categories/vacation/item/1243 -> newsite.se/product-items/1243
```

using this at the bottom on my newsite.se routes.rb:

```
match '*not_found_path', :to => 'redirections#not_found_catcher', via: :get, as: :redirect_catcher, :constraints => lambda{|req| req.path !~ /\.(png|gif|jpg|txt|js|css)$/ }
```

This works fine.

Edit 20151223: The reason I use Newsite.se to handle the redirects is because it holds all the logic of where to redirect the paths. This is virtually impossible for Oldsite.com/.nu to know.

**Actions taken**

Outside of redirecting with 301 (as far as I understand, I do). I have also used Google Webmaster Tools to make a "Request to change address" from my old two websites to my new one. I can't find any information on this any longer but I am quite sure I got a positive response from WMT this hade been done (but I am not 100% sure).

**The problem indications**

I am not 100% sure there is something wrong but I have seen indications that makes me believe the redirection is not made properly so that Google really realize the websites are not moved.

- In Google Webmaster Tools, and "Incoming links" the top link domain is herokuapp.com which in term means oldsite.com. I.e. the 301 redirects seems to be interpreted as links (and not as redirects).
- I often get new indications on Google WMT about "Not founds/404's" (don't know what this section is called in the English version) for url's that could not be reached on newsite.se. When I check the source of those url's I often see links from e.g. oldsite.nu/oldpath/productitem/1234 - like someone (Google?) still have accessed that old url. An important part of this is that I did NOT have that many links to the old sites so I don't expect these to be from old links still feeding traffic.
- I still get traffic to many of my old paths (from oldsite.com/oldsite.new). I find this through my redirection controller which handles plenty of requests on old paths every day.
- The website have lost a lot of positions in Google SERP, this is only a weak indication though since there could be numerous reasons for it.

**Solving the problem**

- How should I go about to trouble shoot this problem?
- Is it normal for WMT to consider 301's as links?
- Is there a smarter way to handle the redirection from oldsite.com than my routes.rb-match line?

Comment: did this answer your question?

Comment: if the comments were sufficient please mark correct

Answer (score 3):

I had to do a similar move for a client moving a large e-commerce website that required transitioning all old traffic to the new website and redirect the appropriate products to the new pathing.

In order to get everything transitioned so we didn't lose Google Ranking we had to implement 301 redirects as you mentioned above. In the WMT they seem to rely on you to handle this instead of have it as a supported function anymore.

**Approach**

> You should redirect every URL on your old domain to the corresponding
>   new URL. That is the documented & recommended way of changing your
>   domain according to Google.

The best approach would be to handle the redirects in a controller and have the logic to send it to the actual page with a 301 and no more redirects once landing on the new website.

I would suggest the following:

**routes.rb** **(oldsite.com/oldsite.nu)**

*Match the request and send it to a controller to handle the finer logic and 301.*

```
match "/(*path)", to: 'redirector#catch_all',  via: [:get, :post]
```

**RedirectorController** **(oldsite.com/oldsite.nu)**

```
def catch_all
    # Separate the rest of the link into its components
    # I will use the example of the vacation -> product-items you have
    options = params[:path].split('/')
    options.reject! { |e| e.to_s.empty? } # Remove trailing junk if any
    if options[0] == 'categories'
        redirect_to "http://www.newsite.se/product-items/#{options.last}", notice: 'Product Updated! We Have A New Site.', status: 301
        return # the return here is a MUST for more complex if-then and multiple redirect_to's
    elsif options[0] == 'contact'
        redirect_to "http://www.newsite.se/contact-us", notice: 'We moved, Contact us Here.', status: 301
        return
    elsif options.empty? || options.blank?
        redirect_to "http://www.newsite.se/", notice: 'That page no longer exists, Please browse our new site', status: 301
        return
    else
        more_sorting(options)
    end
end

private

def more_sorting(options)
    case options
    when options[2].....
        redirect_to ....., notice: '', status: 301
        return
    when options[3].....
        redirect_to ....., notice: '', status: 301
        return
    when options[4].....
        redirect_to ....., notice: '', status: 301
        return
    end
end
```

**Why do it this way:**

This will cause the search engines robots, and users to still be able to crawl and visit each page and link and get redirected to the specific page it is associated to on the new website.

Further it handles the 301 redirect on this server and does not result in another redirect on the new server. Something you may be penalized for from both and user experience and robot interpretation of you're attempts to unite the sites. (this will also most likely remove the interpretation of link 301's)

If you need more complex routing you can add (as I had to do) private functions in the RedirectController for more in depth analysis of the parameters that I had as the last `else` in the *if then* .

**Clarification?**

Let me know if you have any other questions and if this helped.

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed response (and sorry for my delayed response). I thought I had pointed out in my questions (I hadn't) that all the logic of where the paths should be redirected lies in the Newsite and cannot be anywhere else. Basically, it would be quite impossible for Oldsite.com/Oldsite.nu to know where to direct the traffic.

Comment: This part of your answer "Further it handles the 301 redirect on this server and does not result in another redirect on the new server. Something you may be penalized for from both and user experience and robot interpretation of you're attempts to unite the sites." intrigues me. Do you have any source that multiple 301's could be penalized? This could be the core of my problem so I need to be really sure before I start a 10h+ remake of the site redirections.

Comment: Regarding the Approach, all my old url:s do point to a new corresponding url so that works fine. But, basically, although your answer was very thorough it is not really applicable to my situation. What I need to get answered is basically: Is your approach the way I must use (which will make things impossible for me) and is this the actual reason why I suffer "loss of SEO" OR is my site in fact doing fine and this is normal?

Comment: Multiple redirects chained together is not a 'best SEO practice' if you will. If it can not be avoided it can not be avoided. You say it would be impossible for the old sites to know where to send the traffic, why is that? Matt Cutts (head of Googles Webspam Team) discourages chained redirects.... 'If you can do it in one hop, that's ideal. Google is willing to follow multiple hops... but if you start getting up into 4 or 5 range, that's a little bit dangerous, since Google might decide not to follow all those redirects. Keep it down to 1 or 2 or maybe 3.' Each time a redirect occurs it...

Comment: diminishes the amount of 'link juice' the new location will get. It's speculated that a single 301 redirect retains 90-99% of the page rank while adding one or two more will diminish up to 15%(?+). Here is a discussion on '301 redirect chains' *https://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4765398.htm*

Comment: Get back to me on why it would be 'impossible' for them to know and I may be able to provide you with an alternative suggestion.

Comment: The difference between the logic btw the new site and the old ones is not perfect and is not something that could be calculated. Basically, I have a db on the new site where I sometimes manually have to select the new path for certain categories and names. I guess I would be able to have external access to this db from oldsite.com/.nu but it would be a bit of a hassle. I am not 100% convinced this would actually solve this issue. I know I could do some work with removing redirect chains byt 90% of them are 2 redirects.

Comment: I can't see though that the real issue is depending on a double link-redirect chain. It seems like Google should still get that the entire website is transferred and not continue to index it! Any thoughts on why that still happens?

Comment: I also had to do an external connect into the old DB of my site and incorporate it into the pathing for their connections. I can show you how to do this very easily using the manually created ActiveRecord models with some customization that can help you get all the record data for manual path parsing if that helps?  Another thing to make sure of is to look at the keywords each of the webpages is ranked for and make sure they are in the meta keywords on the new page.

Comment: The thing about redirecting all the old traffic to the new website and then redirecting again is that the search engine is going to try to transfer those keywords rankings to you top level index page then trickle it down to the next. feel free to shoot me an email and I can pull some stats on the new and old sites to see what is going on. not sure the best way to get you that without leaving it on this public post. I have access to page-keyword-rank data that I can use to analyze your sites and send you excel breakdowns so you can have better data if you do not have already

Comment: I am really grateful for your help and offer to help me out. It feels however we are getting a bit far from the core issue. I really don't believe the link chain is the core problem here (although it might be causing some SEO-drain). The main issue is that Google does not understand the entire website is moved. I am not sure your solution would solve that particular part of the problem?  What it all boils down to is: Does "redirect_to" in the controller do anything different than "match "/(*path)" => redirect {|params, req| "http://www.newsite.se/#{params[:path]}"}" in routes.rb?

Comment: Continuing on my previous comment. I.e. does the fact on having this particular redirect in the controller (as opposed to my match-solution in routes.rb) actually "say" something different to Google? Or is this just a solution to reduce link chains? As it is now, if I google "site:oldsite.com" I get 360 hits with the old url but the content and title from newsite.se (which is really bad). Would your solution help with this you think? It is a bit of a hassle to implement this on oldsite, that is why I am questioning this before trying to implement.

Comment: I figured out I could do a simplified version of your solution (using the controller redirect but still let newsite.se handle the logic). This will probably take a few days before I might see any results. I will get back after that!

Comment: At minimum you can set the HTTP Codes in the controller. Keep me posted.